# Create Joomla Datagrid

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions

I come from a `.NET` background where you can create grids with headers and data in columns/rows to easily display your data.  Is there a Joomla Extension that can do the same?  I want to query `MySQL` and have the results from the query returned to the page in a format similar to the below
(varying columns tho, not just 3 could be more or less)

> Name --- ID --- Age
>   A --- 1 ---- 12
>   B --- 2 ---- 13
>   C --- 3 ---- 22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To query the database, you can use the following:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'name', 'age')))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__table')); 

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

`$results` is now your variable that contains an object of results.

**Note:** If you want to get all data from all columns, then replace:

```
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'name', 'age')))
```

with:

```
$query->select(array('*'))
```

---

You can then add a `foreach` loop and construct your table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        foreach ($results as $row)
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $row->name . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row->id . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row->age . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    ?>  
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Lodder's answer, another option is to use a third party extension such as [ChronoConnectivity](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/chrono-connectivity) (free) or [Alter Reports](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/data-reports/alter-reports) (paid) or similar which help you formulate your query and display the results in the front-end.

Comment: Have you used ChronoConnectivity before?  I see how to create the connection and build out the query, but how do I actually add the returned results to my article?

Comment: I tend to use the [ChronoConnectivity plugin](http://www.chronoengine.com/downloads/chronoconnectivity.html) to insert the results into my articles.